# Is it OK in MVC to split controller into 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a single `BookController` that right now only returns Views. However I also want to retrieve some json data from this controller, for example for my infinite scrolling to work I need to fetch data from my server. Basically it works in this kind of order:

1. On entering `/index` I send the HTML page.
2. On user scrolling to end I fetch additional data from `/api/books/list?page=(some num)` and draw it on `/index`.

So my question is should I split controller into View retrieving and JSON retrieving? Or is it fine to keep it as one?

Comment: This is an opinionated question, there's no good answer.  Controllers are way to logically organize endpoints.   If both endpoints are related to books, it seems like a logical way to organize the two endpoints in a BookController.

Comment: No. The MVC-Police will storm your office and... ;P No, seriously: who is supposed to stop you? If it works and fits your way of organizing things - who cares? The only thing to think about when deviating from beaten paths is that you may have to keep on doing so down the line when it comes to well-established patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others stated in the comments, it's perfectly fine to keep it all in just one controller. They are after all related to each other.

What you could do though, if you want to avoid your controller from getting large, you could split it up into different files by making your class (the controller) partial. One for the views and one for the JSON related methods.

[Check the MSDN docs for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)